# Convergence check in LMFIT

Tags: python, lmfit

I am using the `lmfit` library as implemented for python to do least square fits. Unfortunately, I don't know how to properly estimate the convergence of my results. What I currently do is to start with some tight convergence parameter set and check my fit parameters iteratively. If they are both zero, I reduce these parameters and run again (as shown below).

```
conv=1E-13
out  = lmfit.minimize(residual,out1.params,method='leastsq',xtol=conv,ftol=conv)
if out.params['a'].stderr == 0. or  out.params['b'].stderr == 0.:
   while out.params['a'].stderr == 0. or out.params['b'].stderr == 0.:
       conv=conv*10.
       out  =  lmfit.minimize(residual,out1.params,method='leastsq',xtol=conv,ftol=conv)
```

This tends to work, however, I assume that the same can be done using the output of the fitting function. i.e. a special variable that stores the output status of the calculation `out.parmas.convergence = True`. Checking if the fit function returns zeros is also limited to the default `leastsq` method,since other options like `least_squares` return differently when the fit fails. I am also concerned with the output of `lmfit`. Namely it finishes the print with `None`, which is one output variable too much and is not present in the online references I found.

```
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # function evals   = 16
    # data points      = 21
    # variables        = 2
    chi-square         = 11.408
    reduced chi-square = 0.600
    Akaike info crit   = -8.815
    Bayesian info crit = -6.726
[[Variables]]
    a:       0.09022266 +/- 0.001054 (1.17%) (init= 0.09022267)
    b:       1.49985526 +/- 1.28e-09 (0.00%) (init= 1.5)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
    C(a, b)                  = -0.197
None
```

I would appreciate your ideas and advice.

Comment: First, please post a complete example that shows the problem you are having.  Second, why not use the default tolerances, at least to start with?  What are you hoping to achieve by your approach of preventing the fit from thinking it has converged?

Comment: I hope to achieve a better fit. Running few different calculations I noticed that with the default convergence criteria the fit is not always optimal. My data has the general form of `1/x` and it is possible at least qualitatively to estimate the goodness of the fit. To begin with I would like to find the proper parameter that tells me weather convergence has been achieved.

Comment: the underlying method used (say, `leastsq`) will report if it thinks convergence was reached, in its own way -- there is no uniform meaning for convergence let alone uniform way to report it.  A `lmfit.MinimizerResult` will contain `status` and `success` and `ier` from `leastsq`.   This might be what you are asking for.  But, starting with extremely fine tolerance and relaxing that until the fit succeeds is a poor strategy.  First, demonstrate that the fit works. Second, demonstrate that the default tolerance is too large.  Only then should you reduce the tolerances from their defaults.